# Can the word "anxiety" take the preposition "at" and still sound proper?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I wrote this sentence recently, where I used the preposition *at* after the word *anxiety*.

> I suppose they<sup>1</sup> are valuable in that they reveal our anxiety at being human.

I'm not sure if the preposition *at* can properly follow *anxiety* in this way. I may have done it for the sake of euphony, i.e. *at* rhymes with *that*.

A [quick search on ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anxiety%20at%2Canxiety%20over%2Canxiety%20about%2Canxiety%20concerning%2C%20anxiety%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canxiety%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canxiety%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canxiety%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canxiety%20concerning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canxiety%20on%3B%2Cc0) shows that the phrase "anxiety at" is indeed used, more than "anxiety concerning" and a little less than "anxiety on". The phrase "anxiety over" has a substantial edge and "anxiety about" is most common by far.

But this research is by no means conclusive. It just shows that "anxiety about" is the most common. Which preposition would you choose to complete the sentence? Do you think that using *at* this way is a good choice, or would most people flag it as suspicious?

---

<sup>1</sup> The pronoun here refers to the theories of free will and determinism. To give more context, I was debating whether these theories are useful or just fun to think about.

Comment: It's understandable, but *anxiety about* is better.

Comment: Your NGram has a problem. A lot of the results for "anxiety at" are not how you are using it but rather "anxiety at place/time". Therefore, you cannot use it to make any conclusions about relative frequency.

Answer (score 1):

I consider "anxiety at" to be idiomatic, and in terms of sound as well as precise sense it's a better choice in this sentence than "anxiety about." The preposition *at* means "used to indicate the person or thing toward which an action, motion, or feeling is directed or aimed" (*Merriam-Webster*). "Being human" is a thing, and "anxiety" is a feeling. So there's no question of its being correct. I wouldn't have thought twice about it.

Answer (score 1):

*Anxiety over being human* sounds  more idiomatic, at least in everyday English (not technical contexts).

*Anxiety over being...* can be followed by an adjectival phrase or a  noun phrase. For example, from  *Self-esteem for Dummies*:

> which can then lead to performing at very low levels because your anxiety over being a failure is so high.

*Anxiety over being* can also be followed by an adjective or  adjective phrase.

> Her *anxiety over being left alone in the house* reached epic proportions.

Or

> His *anxiety over being abandoned* finally went away.

Sounds better than *Anxiety at being human*.